# Django Error: Error during template rendering

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm learning Django framework and I have in the extend templates part, I'm trying to add a new template when I click in the title of the post in my blog to redirect to an page with the post details (date/author/etc),so I create a new view in *views.py* and a new url to in *urls.py*,But when I adc the path of the url in the *'href'* desirable of the .html file ,as you will see, I receive the follow error when I reload the page:

> NoReverseMatch at /
>
> Reverse for 'blog.views.post_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword
>   arguments '{'pk': 2}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

**And**

> Error during template rendering
>
> In template
>   /home/douglas/Documentos/Django/my-first-blog/blog/templates/blog/post_list.html,
>   error at line 9

So, when I erase the *href* to back the default value all works well...I am almost sure that something is wrong in the *href* line but I will post all template related files for you to check, if you need to check anything else let me know:

**firs the html file: *post_list.html***

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="post">
            <div class="date">
                {{ post.published_date }}
            </div>
            <h1><a href="{% url 'blog.views.post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
            <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from .models import Post

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post
from django.utils import timezone

def post_list(request):
    #posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

Well guys, I think is that, I hope I have not forgotten any details about my question...
Thank you in advance,any help is welcome!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a name for your url. It's better.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

Like this, in your template, you can use this name on `url` tag

```
<h1><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
```

First info (with name define for url)

> The first argument is a url() name. It can be a quoted literal or any
>   other context variable.

Second info (In your case, url without name)

> If you’d like to retrieve a namespaced URL, specify the fully
>   qualified name:
>
> {% url 'myapp:view-name' %}

[More information here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#url)